# Getting Array Index Out of bound exception while adding elements to a List in Parallel.ForEach in C#

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception, parallel.foreach

I am trying to add elements in a List in C#. I am doing it in a Parallel.ForEach loop. I am getting Array index out of bound execption. What is the solution for this ?

```
var processes = new List<Process>();
Parallel.ForEach(productList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30 }, product =>
{
      // Some Logic               
      processes.Add(process);
}
```

Comment: A `List<T>` is not thread-safe. Use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` or lock around the call to `Add` (which makes it pretty meaningless to use a `Parallel.ForEach` in the first place).

Comment: Actually, introducing a lock shouldn't be that big of a problem. Sure, it'll make adding items to the list be a sequential operation, but I'm assuming the cost of doing that isn't the biggest thing you have in the parallel code, so most of it will still run in parallel.

Comment: True. its not the biggest thing i am doing in the loop. lock solution is also fine but i think delegating synchronization work to the framework itself is a better approach then adding lock explicitly in code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<T>` is not thread-safe. This means that you cannot call its `Add` method from more than one thread simultaneously and expect it to work.

You should replace the list with a `ConcurrentBag<T>`. The other option would be to synchronize the access to the list, for example using a `lock` statement. But if all you do is to simply add an item to the list in your loop, it doesn't make much sense to use a `Parallel.ForEach` and a `List<T>`.